# CSS3 filter blur keyframe animation

Tags: css, animation, filter, blur, keyframe

What I'm trying to accomplish is a short gaussian blur animation on an image hover. Somewhat like setting focus on a camera. (focused-blurred-focused).

This is what I got so far:

```
@-webkit-keyframes image_blur {
    0% { -webkit-filter: blur(0px);}
    50%; { -webkit-filter: blur(5px);}
    100% { -webkit-filter: blur(0px);}
}

#image {
    width    : 290px;
    height   : 160px;
    background: url(images/test1.jpg);
}

#image:hover {
    -webkit-animation: image_blur 2s; 
}
```

Which doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions?

Comment: whenever possible use a good IDE, solves most of the syntax error itself. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove the ";" after "50%" in your `@-webkit-keyframes`.
It will work.

```
0% { -webkit-filter: blur(0px);}
50%; { -webkit-filter: blur(5px);}
100% { -webkit-filter: blur(0px);}
```

Use this instead

```
0% { -webkit-filter: blur(0px);}
50% { -webkit-filter: blur(5px);}
100% { -webkit-filter: blur(0px);}
```

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that. Thanks, mate.